# Servlet does not get request parameter

Tags: java, servlets, redirect

The servlet redirects from page1.jsp to page2.jsp like this:

```
String url = getServletContext().getContextPath() + "page2.jsp?command=reload";
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

Than the filter which try to get "command" parameter can get it. But servlet does not see the parameter. 
I also tried to do this without any filters. The result is the same.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your servlet here? The one that you get by compiling `page2.jsp` as a servlet? If that's the case, make sure you are retrieving the parameter correctly by using:

```
request["command"]
```

If your servlet is a real servlet (no JSP page), then you need to map a URL to that servlet and invoke the servlet with that URL mapping.

Make sure you post more info so you will get better help.

Comment: It's real servlet which has a mapping in web.xml. I use MVC pattern. So servlet is controller. And controller has to get parameter from request from "page2.jsp?command=reload".
It seems I understand. Thank you!